# Finding minimum point of banana function using Newton's Method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I am using the banana function $F(x_1,x_2)=(1-x_1)^2+100(x_2-x_1^2)^2$ over $x_1,x_1 \in \Re$.  I am using $f_1(x_1,x_2)=0, f_2(x_1,x_2)=0$ to find the minimum point of $F$ which it is (1,1).

Now I want to implement Newton's method for finding the minimum of $F$ via $f_1=f_2=0$ starting with initial condition $x_0=(1.2,1.2)^T$.

How can I do and how can I use Newton's method for finding the minimum point of $F$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given the [*Rosenbrock Function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function), sometimes called the banana function with $a = 1, b = 100$ and asked to find the minimum using Newton's method with a starting point $X_0 = (x, y) = (1.2, 1.2)$ as:

$$f(x,y)=(1-x)^2+100(y-x^2)^2$$

Newton's method can be extended for the minimization of multivariable functions.

The iteration is given by:

$$X_{n+1} = X_n - [J_n]^{-1} \nabla f_n$$

where:
$$ \nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 (1 - x) - 400 x (-x^2 + y) \\ 200 (-x^2 + y) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} & \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 + 800 x^2 + 400 (x^2 - y) & 400 x \\ -400 x & 200
\end{bmatrix}$$

The iterates are:

- $X_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
   1.2 \\ 1.2
  \end{bmatrix}$
- $X_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
   1.19592 \\ 1.4302
  \end{bmatrix}$
- $X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
   1.00065 \\ 0.963172
  \end{bmatrix}$
- $X_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
   1.00058 \\ 1.00115
  \end{bmatrix}$
- $X_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
   1. \\ 1.
  \end{bmatrix}$
- $X_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
   1. \\ 1.
  \end{bmatrix}$

Here is a graphical representation of the Newton iterates:

[image]